# rails paperclip S3 with dynamic bucket name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm using paperclip to upload my documents to Amazon S3. I would like to automatically create a bucket with the ID of my projects when I upload a new document.

Therefore, in my controller, I have this:

```
 def new
    @pmdocument = Pmdocument.new
    @pmdocument.projectmilestone_id=params[:projectmilestone_id]
```

where projectmilestone_id is the foreign_key to my project (to be used as my bucket name)

My model is like this:

```
class Pmdocument < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :projectmilestone
  attr_accessible :id, :name, :description, :projectmilestone_id, :pmdoc, :projectmilestone_attributes
  attr_protected :pmdoc_content_type, :pmdoc_size
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :projectmilestone, :allow_destroy => false
  has_attached_file :pmdoc,
    :storage => :s3,
    :bucket => self.projectmilestone_id.to_s,
    :s3_credentials => File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 's3.yml')
```

When I load the page, I get this error: 
undefined method `projectmilestone_id' for #

I checked my controller and the projectmilestone_id field is correctly loaded there.

I tried to change the bucket line to `:bucket => self.name` and then the error is gone.

The model works ok because projectmilestone_id is correctly stored in the db.

My guess is that it could be linked to the accessible attributes but it seems to be ok too.

What's wrong?  Many thanks!!!

---

I really dont get it:

I decided not to change my bucket anymore (bad idea anyway as the name need to be unique for all S3) but to change my path instead.

This is the code:

```
:path => proc { |attachment| "#{attachment.istance.projectname}/:attachment/:id/:basename.:extension" },
```

The first folder with my project name is not created. If I replace projectname by name, or even description (another field of pmdocuments), it works, but not with projectname. Of course, I checked that projectname is correctly populated. The reason is elsewhere.

Any clue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `has_attached_file` method is executed in the context of the class (when the file is loaded), not in the context of a record instance where you could use attributes and other instance method. `self.name` works indeed, but it returns the name of the class (`"Pmdocument"`), not the name of a record.

But Paperclip is kind enough to allow what you want. The [documentation on the S3 storage](http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/master/Paperclip/Storage/S3) says:

> You can define the bucket as a Proc if
>   you want to determine it’s name at
>   runtime. Paperclip will call that Proc
>   with attachment as the only argument.

In your case it would be something like this:

```
has_attached_file :pmdoc,
  :storage => :s3,
  :bucket => proc { |attachment| attachment.instance.projectmilestone_id.to_s },
  :s3_credentials => File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 's3.yml')
```

Now you pass a [Proc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Proc.html) to `has_attached_file`. The content of the block is not evaluated while your class is loaded, but later when it's needed. Paperclip then calls the block with the [attachment](http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/master/Paperclip/Attachment) as argument and uses the returned value as bucket name.

Edit:

Unfortunately, this block is run when the file is assigned, not when the record is saved. So all your attributes may not be set yet (the order of the assignment of the attributes when you do `Pmdocument.new(params[:pmdocument])` is undetermined). I'd like Paperclip to work another way, but in the meantime I see 2 options:

You can remove the file from the params in the controller and set it when everything else is ready:

```
pmdoc = params[:pmdocument].delete(:pmdoc)
@pmdocument = Pmdocument.new(params[:pmdocument])
@pmdocument.pmdoc = pmdoc
```

Or you can delay Paperclip post-processing by disabling it with `before_post_process` (see the Events section of the [README](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/README.md)) and running it in an [`after_save` callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

Comment: Thank you for this very very helpful explanation. I'm new to rails and to OO programming and I haven't caught everything yet. I did what you tell above but apparently, I can't create a bucket with a digit as a name. So I tried to use my relationships to get back to the project's name: proc { |attachment| attachment.instance.projectmilestone.projectcapstone.project.name.to_s } but I have another error : "undefined method `projectcapstone' for nil:NilClass". This is strange because my class doesn't seem to be nil as it works without going through the relationships. What's wrong this time? Thx!!!

Comment: The block may be executed when you assign the file (maybe a line like `pmdocument.pmdoc = params[...]` or `pmdocument.update_attributes(...)`). Make sure your object has a valid `projectcapstone` before this assignment.

Comment: The fact that the config options actually *can* be given a lambda/proc with a parameter (the attachment) saved my life. Thanks a lot! <3